# Android - Switching activity with different implementation

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes in Java and they are 2 different activities that I'd like to switch with a button click.

The problem is that when I do click the button the app crashes.

my `MainActivity` extends `Activity` and my `SecondActivity` extends `Activity` AND implements `SensorEventListener`. So I think this is the problem. My MainActivity CANNOT implement `SensorEventListener` because I am using an external sensor.

This is my MainActivity

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//My Code goes here.

//This it the function that gets called from XML's onClick feature when I click my Button
public void gotoPathFinder(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, pathfinderActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is my SecondActivity

```java
package ca.concordia.sensortag.minimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class pathfinderActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
    private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;

    private TextView textView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(this.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
//      Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
//      float[] values = event.values;
//      int value = -1;
//
//      if (values.length > 0) {
//          value = (int) values[0];
//      }
//
//      if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
//          textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
//      } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
//          textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + value);
//      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);      
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

So I think the app crashes because I'm trying to switch to an activity that implements sensoreventlistener from an activity that doesn't? How can I fix this issue?

---

LogCat

```
11-27 20:00:07.312: W/dalvikvm(31178): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41604ba8)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178): Process: ca.concordia.sensortag.minimal, PID: 31178
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method gotoPathFinder(View) in the activity class ca.concordia.sensortag.minimal.pathfinderActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'pf_button'
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: gotoPathFinder [class android.view.View]
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
11-27 20:00:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(31178):    ... 11 more
```

NOTE: When I click the button it brings me to the SAME activity... and then i click the button again THEN i get an error

---

MainActivity's XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ca.concordia.sensortag.minimal.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/compass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/compass" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pointer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pointer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pf_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/compass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pf_button"
        android:onClick="gotoPathFinder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your logcat output.

Comment: You don't need to "think" anything. You need to just look at your logcat

Comment: I've updated the post with logcat. NOTE: I've only put the errors of the logcat. Hope that's ok

Comment: I've added a note in the post. might be helpful to detect the error

Comment: post your layout xmls

Comment: I've added MainActivity XML file

Comment: Could not find a method in the activity class --> Are you calling gotoPathFinder() in the correct Activity which is MainActivity? Perhaps it is best to eliminate time wasting for both you and all of us by posting the entire code.

Comment: There. I've posted the entire pathfinderActivity code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont have the method gotoPathFinder in your pathfinderActivity class, am I right that you have also a view with an onclick event in this class too that calls this method?

you do this in your second class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

so your second class has same layout like your first class. first time you click the button the acticity changes but layout stays the same then when you click it again there is no method in the current class that the botton onclick can run and switch to the other class

so if you have 2 separate layouts you want to use then switch the lone above with

```
setContentView(R.layout.other_acticity);
```

and if its intended then add method with same name to second class

Comment: um... why would i need that method INSIDE pathfinderActivity? I am switching TO that class

Comment: look at this line in pathfinderActivity: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
@Matin see my edit

Comment: happens to everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

This is your error:

> Could not find a method gotoPathFinder(View)
>   android.widget.ImageView with id 'pf_button'

In your XML, find the `ImageView` with the id "pf_button".

For that `ImageView`, get rid of whatever `android:onClick` is already there, and change it to this:

```
android:onClick="gotoSecond"
```

You just had the wrong method name in the XML file...your app was looking for that name, but couldn't find it!

Let me know if that works. It should.

Comment: I do have that. 
`<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pf_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/compass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pf_button"
        android:onClick="gotoPathFinder" />`

Comment: No, in the code you just gave me, you have `android:onClick="gotoPathFinder` - that's wrong. Change it to `android:onClick="gotoSecond`. Read my answer!

Comment: I've added a note in the post. might be helpful to detect the error

Comment: the name of my function IS `gotoPathFinder`. (it was my mistake when I made the post. I corrected it)

Comment: @Matin what are the names of your two classes?

Comment: the main class from which I want to switch is `MainActivity` and the second is `pathfinderActivity`

Comment: Ok. I think I know what your problem might be. Can you show me the first couple of lines of your onCreate method in your second activity? Specifically the line where you set the layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65782/discussion-between-matin-and-alex-k).